# How to use Record Type as List/Record?

Tags: netsuite

I have 2 Record Type [Sales Quotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HUiy.png) & [Status SQ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3k8ng.png)

What I want to do is the list show field "Customer Status" from Record Type Status SQ not show the 'Internal ID' like this one
[Sales Quotation List Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGxs1.png)

any idea on how to get that as list?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe solution would be to go edit Status SQ record and check 'Include name field'. Then keep same values for Name and Customer Status or you can source value from one to another.

Answer (score 0):

As solution you can try do this :

1. Edit the Status SQ record to include the name field.
2. In the  Sales Quotation record edit the custom form and rename the 'Name' field as 'Customer status'.